# Use RTK Query inside a hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-scroll, rtk-query

I want ta call a RTK Query inside a function to implement some infinite scroll (by fetching new group of data each time it is needed by calling `loadMore`), so I've tried to use state (`myDataState`) but with no success. Currently I request all data at first, it works but it is not at all optimized as there is potentially lots of data.

The query itself work well

Does someone have an idea?

PS: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-hook?activeTab=readme

```
export const useLoadItems = (type: dataType = dataType.friends) => {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([]);
const [hasNextPage, setHasNextPage] = useState<boolean>(true);
const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();
const [dataToDisplay, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);
const [arraySize, setArraySize] = useState<number>(ARRAY_SIZE);

const dataP = { offset: 0, limit: 5 };
const [myDataState, setDataState] = useState(dataP);

const result = useGetAllSessionsPaginatedQuery(myDataState);

const loadItems = (
  startCursor = 0,
  data: any[],
  arraySize = ARRAY_SIZE,
  type: dataType,
): Promise<Response> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let newArray: Item[] = [];
    /*FIXME use result.data*/
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = startCursor; i < startCursor + arraySize; i++) {
        if (i < data.length) {
          const newItem = {
            key: i,
            value: data[i],
          };
          newArray = [...newArray, newItem];
        }
      }

      resolve({ hasNextPage: true || startCursor + arraySize < data.length, data: newArray });
    }, RESPONSE_TIME_IN_MS);
  });
};

const loadMore = async (reset: boolean = false) => {
  setLoading(true);
  if (reset) {
    items.splice(0);
    setHasNextPage(true);
  }
  const dataP = { offset: items.length, limit: arraySize };
  setDataState(dataP);
  console.log(result.data);

  try {
    const { data, hasNextPage: newHasNextPage } = await loadItems(
      items.length,
      dataToDisplay,
      arraySize,
      type,
    );
    setItems((current) => [...current, ...data]);
    setHasNextPage(newHasNextPage);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    setError(err as SetStateAction<Error | undefined>);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

return { loading, items, setData, hasNextPage, error, loadMore, setArraySize };
```

};

Answer (score 0):

you can use `lazy` like: `useLazyGetAllSessionsPaginatedQuery()` in this way you can write the hook like this:

```
const [loadData, { isLoading, isError}] = useLazyGetAllSessionsPaginatedQuery();
```

and finally, u have a state for storing all the data as you did.

```
const size = 10;
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
const [allList, setAlllist] = useState([]);


const LoadMore  = async () => {
    // if you have pagination then you can do something like this.
   const result = await loadData({page, size, filter});

    setAllState((prevList) => {
        const newList = [...prevList, ...result];
        return newList;
    })

}
```

in this way whenever you click on LoadMore you run `loadData` and merge the new data with the old one. and if your API has pagination support you can fetch 10 items per page.